# Call parent key value of nested dictionary

Tags: python

Using nested dictionaries,

I am curious about how to use the key value at the bottom to call the key value above it.

Below is a nested dictionary entry.

```
test_1 = {
    'test_1_node' : {
    'A':{'B':8, 'C':1, 'D':2},
    'B':{},
    'C':{'B':5, 'D':2},
    'D':{'E':3, 'F':5},
    'E':{'F':1},
    'F':{'A':5}
    } , #노드 정의
    
    'test_1_location' : {
        'A':(73,318),
        'B':(283,90),
        'C':(283,318),
        'D':(283,534),
        'E':(490, 318),
        'F':(490, 534)
    } , #찍은 노드 이미지로 표시하기위한 좌표값 표시
    
    'test_1_floor' : 1 #층정보 표시
}
```

By using these nested dictionaries,`start_node = test_1_node['test_1']['A']` was called to call the lowest value.

What is the method to select the test_1_floor of the top test_1 dictionary using this 'A' value?

I know how to dig down, nest it like this dict[key1][key2], but I don't know how to get it back up again

Comment: Maintain a reverse dictionary or search the entire dict for that value.

Comment: I guess you mean `start_node = test_1['test_1_node']['A']` was called.

Comment: The "code" in the text of your question doesn't correlate with the dictionary structure

Comment: You will probably also want to separate each of those dictionaries from each other since they store different data. Won't change the code much, but will make it easier to read / modify